# MaxAllowedContentLength is not working properly after updated once

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

The following is the chronology of the issue:

- Downloaded file (`.zip` in this case) seems to be limited at 97.660KB, anything exceeding that would results in a corrupted file
- Found out the value of `Maximum allowed content length (Bytes):` is 150,000,000
- Updated the value to 300,000,000 and then `iisreset` and the website allows download up to 224,820 KB
- Attempted to change the value to its initial condition and then `issreset` which is 150,000,000 but however it still allows download file size bigger then the supposed value.

The following is the latest condition of the `web.config` file:

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="150000000" />
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Reverting the maximum download size allowed

Comment: Check for any parent configuration files that might override that maxAllowedContentLength setting, verify that the values in those files are also set to the desired limit. Also, if your application has multiple virtual directories or subapplications, each virtual directory or subapplication may have its own web.config file. Make sure you are modifying the correct web.config file for your particular website or application.

Comment: @YurongDai I have confirmed on the parents directory (Default Web Site) that the value set even smaller at 30,000,000 but when I check the `web.config` file the last modified date did not reflect to the date I made this change on.
As per today I rollback the entire website but the issue is persisting.

Comment: Could it be some caching mechanism exists? This can happen at the server level, application level, or even client-side caching. Try clearing your browser cache or downloading with another browser to make sure it's not a client-side cache issue.

Comment: @YurongDai The issue persist on different browser, I think it's safe to assume the issue is on the server side. 
I have been thinking if the `maxAllowedContentLength` was 150,000,000 the website should not be limited at 97KB however the download limit was indeed increased after cranking up the value from IIS. Could it be that changing the value on IIS change something else?

I have cleared the cache from server side by clearing: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP
Please do tell if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `applicationhost.config` on `System32/inetsrv/Config`.
For some reason when `MaxAllowedContentLength` is changed from IIS (version 10.0.14393.5921) and this attribute is absent it will automatically have `MaxAllowedContentLength` set on 0 and won't reflect to the set value in IIS.

Edit:
I couldn't find out exactly how to reliably trigger the behavior I have mentioned above, but just to be sure you could check that file just in case because it takes priority over `Web.config`

The solution is to delete `MaxAllowedContentLength` from `applicationhost.config` or have it set correctly right there.

Comment: Glad you found the solution! If you could mark your answer, it would lead more people in the right direction.

Comment: @YurongDai Thank you for your answer as well! since now I am aware of the cache file I am adding it to my check list for the following deployment.